# Where is this dockerfile putting files in the container?

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker to build an ASP site, and I'm confused about where my files are going.  Here's my dockerfile (the application is called AspCore)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build

ARG BUILDCONFIG=RELEASE
ARG VERSION=1.0.0

COPY AspCore.csproj /build/

RUN dotnet restore ./build/AspCore.csproj

COPY . ./build/
WORKDIR /build/
RUN dotnet publish ./AspCore.csproj -c $BUILDCONFIG -o out /p:Version=$VERSION

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /build/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AspCore.dll"]
```

This works correctly and I can access the site when I run the image, but I don't quite understand how this is working.  When I open a shell to my container, I don't see a `build` directory either in the `app` directory or in the base directory.  I also can't find the `AspCore.csproj` file.

Isn't the dockerfile copying `AspCore.csproj` into the `build` directory, so shouldn't there be a `build` directory with a bunch of files in it on my container?  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Is it in the root (`/build`)? Customarily, you'd put a `WORKDIR ...` near the top of your file to define this working directory. Subsequent `COPY` and `ADD` commands would then be relative to the value of `WORKDIR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just because you're using 2 stage on your Dockerfile to build your image.

**Stage 1**: **(BUILD)** Based on `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build` image to build your source code into dll files

**Stage 2**: **(SERVE)** Based on `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime` to create a runtime for your dlls, in this stage you've already copy files from previous stage into a folder called `app` by this line `COPY --from=build /build/out .`.

After stage 2 copied files from stage1, nothing else you can see from stage1 but copied files, that's why when you start your container you didn't see `/build` folder

This pattern is good for production build when you want to minimize your image, because actually we don't need `sdk` in production environment, we just need `runtime` for the compiled code.

Hope that clear enough, for more information, you can take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/advanced-multi-stage-build-patterns-6f741b852fae)